# Flink managed state as transient

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Why is it important to mark flink state as transient.

Example below uses ValueState and is marked as transient.
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#using-keyed-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RichFunction` is serialized by the Flink client and sent to the Flink cluster, where each task manager will deserialize a copy of it. It doesn't make sense for the `ValueState` object to be included -- instead we want each task manager to have its own `ValueState` object that gets initialized in the `open` method.

Comment: What if state is not marked transient but its initialized in the open method itself.
like this:

private MapState<Integer, Boolean> mapState;
public void open(Configuration conf) {
        mapState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(mapStateDescriptor);
}

Comment: I prefer to use transient to clearly indicate what's going on, but as long as you don't try to initialize the state variable in the client it should be fine.

Comment: On a related note, don't use "lazy" with state variables. This may appear to work fine, but it's better to get any state migrations done during the startup phase, rather than arbitrarily later.